# Getting the index of a key in Stylus

Tags: javascript, node.js, stylus

SASS has a built in index function that returns a keys position in an array. I have been searching for hours to see if Stylus has any kind of similar function, but so far haven't found anything. Does anyone know of a function like this in Stylus or a way to implement something like it using the Stylus Javascript API?

As an example, I am trying to recreate this Bootstrap function in Stylus:

```
grid-breakpoints := {
  xs: 0,
  sm: 544px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px
}

@function breakpoint-next($name, $breakpoints: $grid-breakpoints, $breakpoint-names: map-keys($breakpoints)) {
  $n: index($breakpoint-names, $name);
  @return if($n < length($breakpoint-names), nth($breakpoint-names, $n + 1), null);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this question in the issues section of the Stylus repo and got an answer pretty quickly from one of the main contributors. Here is a link to the issue https://github.com/stylus/stylus/issues/2077.